# How to get wiki titles from php?

Tags: php

How to get titles from wikipedia using api.php? Trying:

```
$opts = array('https' =>
  array(
    'user_agent' => 'MyBot/1.0 (https://example.com/)'
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Your_Highness&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=0';
dump(file_get_contents($url));
```

But it always returns false.

Comment: This code, with `var_dump` instead of `dump` works well for me.
You created a context but you never use it : `file_get_contents($url, false, $context)` I suppose ?

Comment: why not use curl?

Comment: Joffrey Schmitz, dump and var_dump returns NULL now (with or without $context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation you just need to pass format=json when you call API so you will get the response in JSON and based on JSON object you can access any value from a response.

```
    <?php
       $url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Your_Highness&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=0&format=json';
       $context = stream_context_create(['http' => [
               'ignore_errors' => true,
       ]]);
       $body = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    ?>
```

Also, you can use curl for the same like this.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$response = curl_exec( $ch );

if ( $response === false) {
    $curl_result = curl_error( $ch );
    print_r( $curl_result );
} else {        
    print_r( json_decode($response) );
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: jigar halani, thanks for your answer, but now it returns NULL

Comment: @vbm still it's working for me and returning JSON object.

Check this url and press run button it will show you output.

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/nkyk-hx47

Comment: on phpfiddle it works for me too, but on my website (https) still returns NULL

Comment: @vbm which version of php are you using ?

Comment: @vbm use curl instead of file_get_content check updated answer and let me know its working or not